# How do I get dompdf to ignore conditional content?

Tags: dompdf

I have a CakePHP script that prints a report with large blocks of conditional content like so:

```
<?php if(in_array('Medical', $filter) || in_array('All', $filter)){ ?>
<div class="title_col_cell" align="left">Medical</div>
<div class="title_col_cell1" align="right">Visits</div>
<div class="title_col_cell1" align="right">Unduplicated Clients</div>
<div class="title_col_cell1" align="right">Prescription Assistance</div>
<div class="title_col_cell1" align="right">Vaccinations</div>
<?php } ?>
```

When I create a print view of this report, dompdf seems to be rendering the conditional content as blank space. Is there a way to get dompdf not to render that stuff? There are too many possible combinations for me to make a separate view for each. How can I code this differently?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a sample HTML document? Are you parsing the PHP before passing it to dompdf? I can't see a reason the content would be processed as part of the document if it's excluded by the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that's displayed on the screen if you view the document will get to dompdf generated doc. If you can't see it in html document - then it will be hidden. View your document just before you pass it to dompdf in a standard browser to see whats going in there.

Answer (score 0):

DOMPDF pdf will create pdf only for the code which has been sent to it. It's better you put the whole code in a string and then display it on screen to check whether all required html is there or not, before sending to dompdf object. For example :

```
 $str="<div class="title_col_cell" align="left">Medical</div>
       <div class="title_col_cell1" align="right">Visits</div>
       <div class="title_col_cell1" align="right">Unduplicated Clients</div>
       <div class="title_col_cell1" align="right">Prescription Assistance</div>
       <div class="title_col_cell1" align="right">Vaccinations</div>";

 $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
 $dompdf->load_html($str);
 $dompdf->set_paper('letter', 'landscape');
 $dompdf->render();
 $dompdf->stream("dompdf_out.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));

 exit(0);
```